# Как обойти асинхронности при записи в базу дублирующих данных?

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность, sequelize.js

Нужно записать в базу такой запрос:

```
parseCarList =
[ { car_name: 'WV', parent_Id: null },
  { car_name: 'Skoda', parent_Id: 'WV' },
  { car_name: 'Opel', parent_Id: 'Skoda' },
  { car_name: 'Ford', parent_Id: 'Skoda' },
  { car_name: 'Peugeot', parent_Id: 'Skoda' },
  { car_name: 'GM', parent_Id: 'WV' },
  { car_name: 'Opel', parent_Id: 'GM' }, //Ошибка
  { car_name: 'Ford', parent_Id: 'GM' }, //Ошибка
  { car_name: 'Porche', parent_Id: 'GM' },
  { car_name: 'Peugeot', parent_Id: 'GM' }, //Ошибка
  { car_name: 'Tesla', parent_Id: 'Peugeot' } ]
```

Не будем в даваться в иерархию брендов и их реальной причастности друг к другу.

Задача по циклу писать в базу производителя и его родителя если таковой имеется.

```
parseCarList.forEach(item => {
    if (item.car_name) { //если есть car_name
    db.cars.findAll({where: {name: item.car_name}})
        .then(function (validCar) {
            if (validCar.length > 0) { // если нашли
                item.carid = validCar[0].dataValues.id;
                //тут еще будет записываться в базу родитель
            }
            if (validCar.length < 1) { // если не нашли
                createNewCar(item)
                    .then(function (createdCar) {
                        item.carid = createdCar.dataValues.id;
                        //тут еще будет записываться в базу родитель
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
           }
       })
       .catch(error => console.log('Validation: ' + item.car_name + ' found Error: ' + error));
    }
});
```

Все пишет прекрасно (все машины в базу пишутся) кроме тех  дублирующих позиций, что я пометил "Ошибка", а ошибку я получаю т.к. запросы идут асинхронно и к тому моменту как проходят все итерации цикла, база не успевает создать производителя и дублирующий запрос с этим же производителем не находя его в базе пытается сделать этого производителя заново, но видимо к тому моменту как уже начнет делать в базе такая запись уже будет, поле car_name unique: true и я получаю ошибку:

```
New Car Opel not created, Error: SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
```

Красивый вид ошибок я еще допилю, не обращаем внимания.

Выход писать синхронно и ждать каждую созданную машину? А если на какой то машине база застрянет?

Добавлю что я хочу получить в итоге:

В итоге я хочу получить 2 таблицы в БД
1. Cars с полями id, car_name
2. Parents с полями id, car_id, parents_id

Таблица Cars будет выглядеть например так:

```
id=1, car_name=WV
id=2, car_name=Skoda
id=3, car_name=Opel
id=4, car_name=GM
```

Таблица Parents будет выглядеть например так:

```
id=1, car_id=2, parents_id=1
id=2, car_id=3, parents_id=2
id=3, car_id=3, parents_id=4
```

Comment: Чтобы точно понять что происходит: выводим в Лог информацию по создаваемым машинам. Создали родителя, Создали 'WV' и т.п.

Comment: Если вы уверены что машина будет, то в вызове записи, поставьте ожидание появления этой машины в базе

Comment: santavital Я точно понимаю что происходит,  логи просмотрены.  Вопрос в другом,  как при асинхронных запросах обеспечить состояние,  когда повторяющиеся машины но с измененными родителями не будут пытаться создавать машины уже стоящие в очереди.

Comment: Чад не совсем понял,  что вы имели в виду.

Comment: Я тоже не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду. Если car_name у вас unique, то что вы хотите сделать, если у вас уже есть такой car_name, но с другим родителем? Изменить родителя? И зачем тогда вам `db.cars.findAll({where: {name: item.car_name}})`? Немного сбивает с толку, что одни и те же строки у вас и carName, и родитель

Comment: @Darth суть в том, что один car_name может иметь много разных родителей. В базу cars я хочу писать поля id, car_name, а в базу parents писать поля car_id (он же ид машины из базы машин), parents_id (он же ид машины из базы машин но со сдвигом)

Comment: Пример: { car_name: 'WV' (id=1), parent_Id: null }; { car_name: 'Skoda' (id=2), parent_Id: 'WV' (parent_id=1) }

Comment: А не проще записать отдельно parents `id int, name text`, а отдельно `cars` с `id int, car_name text, parents [ (parent_id,parent_id,parent_id ... )]`

Comment: @Darth так а что это меняет, я свой массив все равно прохожу по очереди и на каждой итерации буду слать асинхронный запрос в базу и там не важно в каком виде будет parents проблема именно с cars. Как если бы была только одна таблица cars и я бы слал запросы циклично с дублирующими полями но из за медлительности базы дублирующие запросы валидации получали бы ответ, что такого поля пока в базе нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть два варианта. Во-первых, можно предварительно сгруппировать ваши записи по основной записи, в этом вам поможет библиотека вроде linq.js. Также группировку можно и самостоятельно написать, в этом нет ничего сложного.

Второй вариант - вынести операцию "занести car в базу" в отдельную функцию и [мемоизировать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) ее. Звучит сложно, но делается просто.

Во-первых, создаем отдельную функцию, которая ищет в базе car_name и создает новую запись если не находит:

```
function findCar(db, car_name) {
    return db.cars.findAll({where: {name: car_name}})
      .then(found => {
         if (found.length > 0)
           return found[0];

         // тут создаем новую запись car, обратите внимание на return
         return db.create(...).then(...);
      })
}
```

Обратите внимание на две вещи. Во-первых, я возвращаю из функции обещание (Promise). Во-вторых, я не обрабатываю ошибки на этом этапе - в этом нет смысла, ошибку обработает вызывающий код, главное - вернуть ему обещание с ошибкой.

Также можно воспользоваться async/await чтобы код стал более плоским (для выполнения такого кода в node.js вам надо будет запускать ее с ключом `--harmony`):

```
async function findCar(db, car_name) {
    var found = await db.cars.findAll({where: {name: car_name}});

    if (found.length > 0)
       return found[0];

    // тут создаем новую запись car
}
```

Теперь при обработке очередного элемента списка вам надо проверить не вызывали ли вы эту функцию с этим параметром раньше, и если вызывали - не повторять вызов. Вы не получите ошибку повторной вставки данных если не будете делать повторную вставку, не так ли?

```
var foundCars = new Map();
var list = parseCarList.map(item => {
    var foundCarPromise = foundCars.get(item.car_name);
    if (!foundCarPromise) {
        foundCarPromise = findCar(db, item.car_name);
        foundCars.set(item.car_name, foundCarPromise);
    }

    return foundCarPromise.then(car => {
        // тут уже добавляете дочерние записи в таблицу Parents
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(...)));
});
```

Также обращаю ваше внимание, что я использовать map вместо forEach чтобы собрать список итоговых результатов всех асинхронных операций. Это позволит вам в дальнейшем дождаться их выполнения.

Опять-таки, с использованием возможностей Harmony код можно сделать не таким развесистым:

```
var foundCars = new Map();
var list = parseCarList.map(async item => {
    var foundCarPromise = foundCars.get(item.car_name);
    if (!foundCarPromise) {
        foundCarPromise = findCar(db, item.car_name);
        foundCars.set(item.car_name, foundCarPromise);
    }

    try {
      var car = await foundCarPromise;

      // тут уже добавляете дочерние записи в таблицу Parents
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(...);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня возьмет время на переваривание прежде чем  отметить как "правильно" )

Comment: Дополнительный вопрос, мне при создании car нужно обязательно вернуть значение id созданного car, чтобы в дальнейшем записать его вместе в таблицу родителя id=1, car_id=2, parents_id=1. можно конечно на этапе "тут уже добавляете дочерние записи в таблицу Parents" заново сделать запрос в таблицу cars по item.car_name но это еще один запрос, может можно как то лаконичней?

Comment: @SergeiR посмотрите внимательнее на примеры кода - там для случая когда запись найдена она возвращается. Для случая ненайденной записи нужно сделать то же самое.

Comment: Он возвращает не значение а Promise.

Comment: Выглядит это как то так: foundCarPromise for BMW:  Promise {
  _bitField: 2097152,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _boundTo: cars }

Comment: @SergeiR перечитайте примеры кода еще раз, внимательнее

Comment: Ну я вроде внимательно прочел, функция findCar возвращает обещание, я просил а есть ли возможность вернуть найденное или созданное значение т.е. данные из бд? Судя по всему нет.

Comment: @SergeiR как вы думаете, что попадает в параметр `car` в строках `return foundCarPromise.then(car => {` или `var car = await foundCarPromise;`?

Comment: У меня undefined

Comment: @SergeiR значит, вы что-то забыли. `return`, например.

Comment: Вот мой код целиком, где car выводит undefined.  https://jsfiddle.net/6bqx742c/

Comment: @SergeiR говорю же: **вы return забыли**

Comment: @SergeiR обновил ответ, чтобы показать где еще return нужен